# Compare data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I'm not sure if the title of this post is correct but I don't have any other idea ;)
I've got 2 tables - *documents* and *privileges*. In the first one are documents records described by 4 attributes (*customer*, *project*, *document category*, *document type*). In the second one are privileges records described by the same attributes + *user*

**EXAMPLE 1**

Documents

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
| ID | Customer | Project | Document category | Document type |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
|  1 | CUST1    | PROJ1   | CAT1              | TYPE1         |   
|  2 | CUST1    | PROJ2   | CAT2              | TYPE1         |
|  3 | CUST2    | PROJ1   | CAT2              | TYPE2         |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Privileges

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------+
| ID | Customer | Project | Document category | Document type | User  |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------+
|  1 | CUST1    |         | CAT1              |               | USER1 |
|  2 |          | PROJ1   | CAT2              |               | USER1 |
|  3 |          | PROJ1   | CAT2              |               | USER2 |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------+
```

So now, I would like to get records from *Documents* for USER1 which match to records from *Privileges*. And there are 2 records - ID 1 and ID 3 from *Documents*. ID 1 from *Documents* match to ID 1 from *Privileges* and ID 3 from *Documents* match to ID 2 from  *Privileges*. Values in *Privileges* has to be the same or null/empty.

**EXAMPLE 2**

Documents

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
| ID | Customer | Project | Document category | Document type |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
|  1 | CUST1    | PROJ1   | CAT1              | TYPE1         |
|  2 | CUST1    | PROJ2   | CAT2              | TYPE1         |
|  3 | CUST2    | PROJ1   | CAT2              | TYPE2         |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Privileges

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------+
| ID | Customer | Project | Document category | Document type | User  |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------+ 
|  1 |  CUST1   |         | CAT2              |               | USER1 |
|  2 |  CUST1   | PROJ1   | CAT1              |  DTYPE2       | USER1 |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------+
```

Now there is only 1 record - ID 2 from *Documents* match to ID 1 from *Privileges*.'

Sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a join between the tables.  But, when the values are `NULL` in `Privileges`, then the field is ignored (that is, `NULL` implies "all").

One way is with a query such as:

```
select d.*
from documents d join
     privileges p
     on (d.customer = p.customer or p.customer is null) and
        (d.project = p.project or p.project is null) and
        (d.documentcategory = p.documentcategory or p.documentcategory is null) and
        (d.documenttype = p.documenttype or p.documenttype is null)
where p.user = 'USER1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Column1 = Column2 or Column2 is null

```
  select dc.* from Documents dc join Privileges pr on 
  (dc.Customer =pr.Customer or pr.Customer is null) and 
  (dc.Project = pr.Project  or pr.Project is null) and
  (dc.Document_category = pr.Document_Category or pr.Document_Category is null)  and 
  (dc.Document_Type =pr.Document_Type or pr.Document_Type is null)
  where pr.[User]='User1'
```

If u want equal values NULL and empty ( ' ' ) values use code bellow

Column1 = Column2 or Column2 is null or Column2 = ''

```
select dc.* from Documents dc join Privileges pr on 
  (dc.Customer =pr.Customer or pr.Customer is null or pr.Customer='') and
  (dc.Project = pr.Project  or pr.Project is null or pr.Project='') and
  (dc.Document_category = pr.Document_Category or pr.Document_Category is null or pr.Document_Category='')  and 
  (dc.Document_Type =pr.Document_Type or pr.Document_Type is null or pr.Document_Type='')
  where pr.[User]='User1'
```

Comment: Or isnull(Column2,'') = ''

Thanks